# Add commas to a CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have a file that I am getting from a Linux **sosreport** and I want to make a pie chart, the problem is that when converting the file to CSV, it doesn't contain commas and creates it as 1 column.

The file looks like this:

```
MemFree:      11988456 kB
Buffers:         47456 kB
Cached:        2304036 kB
SwapCached:        772 kB
Active:        3625348 kB
Inactive:       397832 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:     16306056 kB
LowFree:      11988456 kB
SwapTotal:     8191992 kB
SwapFree:      8122928 kB
Dirty:           50552 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     1434016 kB
Mapped:        2065024 kB
Slab:          123484 kB
PageTables:     121432 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  16345020 kB
Committed_AS: 5883888 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    267500 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359470295 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

Transform the meminfo file into CSV file with like so:

```
df.to_csv('meminfo.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

and I'm also trying to name the columns but I can't.

Sorry but I'm new to the world of Data Visualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the python engine you can define the separator as a regular expression. Add a few more fields to handle the header, indexing and data types and this should give you what you want

```
>>> df=pd.read_csv("test.txt", engine="python", sep=r":?\s+", index_col=0,
... names=["field", "value", "unit"],
... dtype={"field":str, "value":int, "unit":str})
>>> 
>>> df
                       value  unit
field                             
MemFree             11988456    kB
Buffers                47456    kB
Cached               2304036    kB
SwapCached               772    kB
Active               3625348    kB
Inactive              397832    kB
HighTotal                  0    kB
HighFree                   0    kB
LowTotal            16306056    kB
LowFree             11988456    kB
SwapTotal            8191992    kB
SwapFree             8122928    kB
Dirty                  50552    kB
Writeback                  0    kB
AnonPages            1434016    kB
Mapped               2065024    kB
Slab                  123484    kB
PageTables            121432    kB
NFS_Unstable               0    kB
Bounce                     0    kB
CommitLimit         16345020    kB
Committed_AS         5883888    kB
VmallocTotal     34359738367    kB
VmallocUsed           267500    kB
VmallocChunk     34359470295    kB
HugePages_Total            0  None
HugePages_Free             0  None
HugePages_Rsvd             0  None
Hugepagesize            2048    kB
>>>
```

Comment: It worked perfect, thank you very much

later in the code, the column called "field" returns an error:

`KeyError: 'field'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred.`

Im trying to graph a pie chart and it seems that it can't find the column with that name

Comment: @jorgeoxi -If you remove `index_col=0` then field is no longer an index which may make it work as a regular column for you.